# How to prevent an endless deluge of questions about “that” and “which”

Tags: discussion, questions, search, duplicate-questions

I know we have already [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/need-to-be-able-to-search-for-stop-words-on-english-se-because-they-are-often-t) about this problem [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60901/searching-for-which-or-what-doesnt-work-on-english-stackexchange-com), but English.SE has now had its [third](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/that-or-which-does-it-matter) question about the difference between *that* and *which* ([first](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/), [second](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309/)). The “Ask Question” page is supposed to pop up a list of related questions, but because *that* and *which* are both “stop words”, When you start a question on this topic using any of the most obvious obvious ways to phrase the question—for example, “When to use ‘that’ and when to use ‘which’”, “How do I know when I should write ‘that’ or ‘which’”, “‘That’ or ‘Which’: that is the question”—nothing pops up in the Related Questions box.

Are we doomed to forever being unable to warn users that their question has already been asked if it happens to be a question about stop words, which are asked about all the time on English.SE?

Comment: Interesting; I thought most modern fulltext engines didn't even use stopwords anymore for this very reason (they're often an important part of the context).  I'm sure they should be able to edit the stop list for a specific site...

Comment: I wouldn't call three questions in 63 days a _deluge_, but you make a good point. This reminds me of how difficult it is to search for special characters in Google.

Comment: Familiar problem.  Oh no, not yet another question about the ++ operator!  Thousands of them.

Comment: @Hans And the infamous `-->` operator.

Comment: Would be funny if now this question gets asked on meta several times because of the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are [very similar issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62258/what-can-be-done-about-repetitive-questions) on SO proper.

My suggestion would be to create one high-quality reference question, and close all incoming questions as a duplicate of that.

Comment: i don't think this fixes the problem.  As i understand the OP, this good answer can't be searched for.

Comment: @user that's why I said "... and close all incoming questions as a duplicate of that." It will probably be impossible to fix search to cover these cases

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the FAQ.

Comment: No new users read the FAQ. It's only read by users who like the website and have been using it for a while, but those users most likely already know that their question has already been asked. Seriously, when you want a problem solved and you ask about said problem on a website you've never been to, do you stop and read the FAQ first?

Comment: Actually, I do. It doesn't always sink in the first time, but I do try to avoid looking like an idiot (with varying degrees of success). Seriously though, knowing there will always be those who avoid our best efforts to educate, all we can do is try in every practical way, yes?