# How to find a question regarding the negation/not operator (!)?

Tags: support, search

I am sure there are a few questions on SO about usage of the negation operator (!) in C#, but I haven't been able to find them.

How would one go about finding questions that discuss the proper usage of this operator on SO? I'm interested in suggestions regarding whether one should typically follow one or the other of these conventions:

```
if (!isValid) { ... }
```

or

```
if (isValid == false) { ... }
```

I realize this might be something on Programmers.SE instead, also, but the challenge in finding it still exists.

Comment: Well, it's not directly your question since it's not about the negation operator, but [the conventions for boolean logic does have at least one question about it on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true).

Comment: Vaguely related: [searching for "stop words"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/need-to-be-able-to-search-for-stop-words-on-english-se-because-they-are-often-t) and [searching for code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55473/search-just-code) EDIT: There's also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38968/how-to-search-for-special-characters-on-stack-overflow) about searching for special chars, and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters) which is the general case of this question.

Comment: You don't.  Questions about the increment operator (++) are also doomed to be repeated over++ again.

Comment: @Popular Thanks; [the question you linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters) is pretty much what I am asking, as far as search mechanics go. I would still like to be able to find discussions on this subject though. Perhaps I'll try searching for "bang."

Comment: Personally, I'm fond of [searching for beer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60901/searching-for-which-or-what-doesnt-work-on-english-stackexchange-com).